# How can i get the correct file extension in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.4

When I upload a csv file in laravel 5.4, I get 'txt' as the extension. Is there something I'm missing?

**View**

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'transaction/save', 'files' => true]) !!}

{!! Form::file('batch'); !!}

{!! Form::submit('Upload') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller**

```
public function saveBatch(Request $request)
 {
        $file = $request->batch;
        $path = $request->batch->extension();

        dd($path);
 }
```

Comment: it was a typo, not an error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to move the file first, if you don't then the file is actually a temp file with no extension. You could also use:

```
 $request->batch->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

This would return the original filename's extension. More methods at: http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html

Comment: The getClientOriginalExtension() function gave me what i wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get the extension of uploaded file: (If file input name is file)

```
$extension = $request->file->extension();
```

Comment: That is what I'm doing. I get the correct extension for files like images and excel files but when i try uploading a csv file it changes it to txt

Comment: The $request->file->extension() method returns what Symfony guesses the extension is based on MIME Type.